# Android - toggle RelativeLayout on Top of video view

Tags: android, visibility, android-videoview

I am trying to play a video using the code -- the below code works fine

```
 private VideoView mVideoView;

    mVideoView = (VideoView) findViewById(R.id.vvCarView360);
    mVideoView.setVideoPath(path);
    mVideoView.requestFocus();
    mVideoView.setOnTouchListener(this);
    mVideoView.start();
```

```
rlBottomBar = (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.rlView360BottomBar);
```

Now on click of this videoview i am trying to display a bar containing some icons. The Layout for the bar is given below-

**EDIT**: ADDED COMPLETE XML

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

<VideoView
    android:id="@+id/vvCarView360"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:focusable="true"
    android:focusableInTouchMode="true" />

<RelativeLayout
    android:id="@+id/rlView360BottomBar"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:visibility="invisible" >

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/ivView360Backbtn"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
        android:focusable="true"
        android:focusableInTouchMode="true" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/ivView360Playbtn"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:focusable="true"
        android:focusableInTouchMode="true" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/ivView360Homebtn"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
        android:focusable="true"
        android:focusableInTouchMode="true" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

The ontouch listener -

```
 @Override
public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {

    if (event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_UP) {

        switch (v.getId()) {

        case R.id.vvCarView360:
            if (mVideoView.isPlaying()) {

                mVideoView.pause();
            } else {

                mVideoView.start();
            }

            break;
        }
    }
    rlBottomBar.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE); **// This line not getting executed.**
    return true;
}
```

I can see the video getting paused/resumed. This means the on touch listener is getting executed . **Not sure why the Bottom bar is not visible** . Any help will be highly appreciated.

Comment: you have to add you entire xml code here to get the answer. It looks like that your relative layout is overlapped by VideoView? check that

Comment: @TNR : Added the complete xml.

Comment: Add this to your `rlView360BottomBar`: `android:layout_below="@id/vvCarView360"`.

Comment: Thanks for the input guys. I have resolved it . I will post the answer in some time.

Answer (score 0):

You have to use FrameLayout to achieve your requirement. better you use gone instead of invisible. Change your xml code as below.

```
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent" >

<VideoView
    android:id="@+id/vvCarView360"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:focusable="true"
    android:focusableInTouchMode="true" />

<RelativeLayout
    android:id="@+id/rlView360BottomBar"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:visibility="gone" >

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/ivView360Backbtn"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
        android:focusable="true"
        android:focusableInTouchMode="true" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/ivView360Playbtn"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:focusable="true"
        android:focusableInTouchMode="true" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/ivView360Homebtn"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
        android:focusable="true"
        android:focusableInTouchMode="true" />
</RelativeLayout>
</FrameLayout>
```